# Как получить массив данных из java servlet в коде javascript на странице?

Tags: javascript, java, html, servlet

Разбираю  окно поиска с автозаполнением и столкнулся с вопросом, как передать данные из сервлета в страницу html использующую javascript.
код самого сервлета достаточно простой:

```
package app.servlets;

import app.model.Model;

import javax.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

@WebServlet(name = "/SearchServlet")
public class SearchServlet extends HttpServlet {
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        String country = request.getParameter("myCountry");
        System.out.println(country);
        request.setAttribute("country", country);
        doGet(request, response);
    }

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        RequestDispatcher requestDispatcher = request.getRequestDispatcher("views/search.jsp");
        request.setAttribute("countriesList", Model.getInstance().getCountries());
        requestDispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }
}
```

по которому на страницу передается массив данных по атрибуту countriesList из метода Model.getInstance().getCountries(), по которому получаем простой List со списпом стран, код не буду приводить, там все просто.
Но в коде javascript не могу получить этот массив. собственно весь код, скопированный и слегка изменен из обучалки:

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Окно поиска</h1>
    <div>
        <form autocomplete="off" method="post" action="search">
            <div class="autocomplete" style="width:300px;">
                <input id="myInput" type="text" name="myCountry" placeholder="Country">
            </div>
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </div>
    <script>
        function autocomplete(inp, arr) {

            var currentFocus;

            inp.addEventListener("input", function(e) {
                var a, b, i, val = this.value;
                closeAllLists();
                if (!val) { return false;}
                currentFocus = -1;
                a = document.createElement("DIV");
                a.setAttribute("id", this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                a.setAttribute("class", "autocomplete-items");

                this.parentNode.appendChild(a);
                for (i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
                    if (arr[i].substr(0, val.length).toUpperCase() == val.toUpperCase()) {
                        b = document.createElement("DIV");
                        b.innerHTML = "<strong>" + arr[i].substr(0, val.length) + "</strong>";
                        b.innerHTML += arr[i].substr(val.length);
                        b.innerHTML += "<input type='hidden' value='" + arr[i] + "'>";
                        b.addEventListener("click", function(e) {
                            inp.value = this.getElementsByTagName("input")[0].value;
                            closeAllLists();
                        });
                        a.appendChild(b);
                    }
                }
            });
            inp.addEventListener("keydown", function(e) {
                var x = document.getElementById(this.id + "autocomplete-list");
                if (x) x = x.getElementsByTagName("div");
                if (e.keyCode == 40) {
                    currentFocus++;
                    addActive(x);
                } else if (e.keyCode == 38) { //up
                    currentFocus--;
                    addActive(x);
                } else if (e.keyCode == 13) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    if (currentFocus > -1) {
                        if (x) x[currentFocus].click();
                    }
                }
            });
            function addActive(x) {
                if (!x) return false;
                removeActive(x);
                if (currentFocus >= x.length) currentFocus = 0;
                if (currentFocus < 0) currentFocus = (x.length - 1);
                x[currentFocus].classList.add("autocomplete-active");
            }
            function removeActive(x) {
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    x[i].classList.remove("autocomplete-active");
                }
            }
            function closeAllLists(elmnt) {
                var x = document.getElementsByClassName("autocomplete-items");
                for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
                    if (elmnt != x[i] && elmnt != inp) {
                        x[i].parentNode.removeChild(x[i]);
                    }
                }
            }
            document.addEventListener("click", function (e) {
                closeAllLists(e.target);
            });
        }

         var countries = ["Afghanistan","Albania","Algeria","Andorra","Angola","Anguilla","Antigua & Barbuda","Argentina","Armenia","Aruba","Australia","Austria","Azerbaijan","Bahamas","Bahrain","Bangladesh","Barbados","Belarus","Belgium","Belize","Benin","Bermuda","Bhutan","Bolivia","Bosnia & Herzegovina","Botswana","Brazil","British Virgin Islands","Brunei","Bulgaria","Burkina Faso","Burundi","Cambodia","Cameroon","Canada","Cape Verde","Cayman Islands","Central Arfrican Republic","Chad","Chile","China","Colombia","Congo","Cook Islands","Costa Rica","Cote D Ivoire","Croatia","Cuba","Curacao","Cyprus","Czech Republic","Denmark","Djibouti","Dominica","Dominican Republic","Ecuador","Egypt","El Salvador","Equatorial Guinea","Eritrea","Estonia","Ethiopia","Falkland Islands","Faroe Islands","Fiji","Finland","France","French Polynesia","French West Indies","Gabon","Gambia","Georgia","Germany","Ghana","Gibraltar","Greece","Greenland","Grenada","Guam","Guatemala","Guernsey","Guinea","Guinea Bissau","Guyana","Haiti","Honduras","Hong Kong","Hungary","Iceland","India","Indonesia","Iran","Iraq","Ireland","Isle of Man","Israel","Italy","Jamaica","Japan","Jersey","Jordan","Kazakhstan","Kenya","Kiribati","Kosovo","Kuwait","Kyrgyzstan","Laos","Latvia","Lebanon","Lesotho","Liberia","Libya","Liechtenstein","Lithuania","Luxembourg","Macau","Macedonia","Madagascar","Malawi","Malaysia","Maldives","Mali","Malta","Marshall Islands","Mauritania","Mauritius","Mexico","Micronesia","Moldova","Monaco","Mongolia","Montenegro","Montserrat","Morocco","Mozambique","Myanmar","Namibia","Nauro","Nepal","Netherlands","Netherlands Antilles","New Caledonia","New Zealand","Nicaragua","Niger","Nigeria","North Korea","Norway","Oman","Pakistan","Palau","Palestine","Panama","Papua New Guinea","Paraguay","Peru","Philippines","Poland","Portugal","Puerto Rico","Qatar","Reunion","Romania","Russia","Rwanda","Saint Pierre & Miquelon","Samoa","San Marino","Sao Tome and Principe","Saudi Arabia","Senegal","Serbia","Seychelles","Sierra Leone","Singapore","Slovakia","Slovenia","Solomon Islands","Somalia","South Africa","South Korea","South Sudan","Spain","Sri Lanka","St Kitts & Nevis","St Lucia","St Vincent","Sudan","Suriname","Swaziland","Sweden","Switzerland","Syria","Taiwan","Tajikistan","Tanzania","Thailand","Timor L'Este","Togo","Tonga","Trinidad & Tobago","Tunisia","Turkey","Turkmenistan","Turks & Caicos","Tuvalu","Uganda","Ukraine","United Arab Emirates","United Kingdom","United States of America","Uruguay","Uzbekistan","Vanuatu","Vatican City","Venezuela","Vietnam","Virgin Islands (US)","Yemen","Zambia","Zimbabwe"];
         <%--var countries = ${countriesList}--%>
        autocomplete(document.getElementById("myInput"), countries);
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Упуская подробности интересует код из последних строк, именно присвоение переменной countries, сдесь массив прописан в самом коде. но хотелось бы его получить из servlet.
Пробовал через var countries = ${countriesList} и через var countries = document.getElementByID("countriesList") но не получилось, есть подозрение что неправильный тип данных передаю, либо неправильный метод использую. подскажите, в javascript еще далекий человек.

Comment: Хм.. Сервлеты ещё живы? о_О

Comment: А если по существу, можете направить на каком языке и какой технологии лучше создавать серверную часть приложения? Не хочется изучать мертвые иехнологии

Comment: А, стоп. Я с java applet'ами перепутал... Не знаю, я не джавист.

Answer (score 0):

Вопрос от критического недостатка знаний. Банальное несоответствие типов. List нужно приводить в массив javascript с помощью json, либо если не хочется использовать сторонних библиотек с помощью простенького метода:

```
    public static String ListToJavascript(List<String> list){
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("[");
    for(int i=0; i<list.size(); i++){
        sb.append("\"").append(list.get(i)).append("\"");
        if(i+1 < list.size()){
            sb.append(",");
        }
    }
    sb.append("]");
    return sb.toString();
}
```

Comment: Код неправильный и дырявый. Json надо делать нормально.

Comment: На данном этапе мне помог. Но думаю вы правы, нужно реанимировать знания по json, не использовали забыл все что учил.